# Specify the .Net Framework with IKVM

Tags: c#, java, ikvm

I compiled a Java application to a C# dll with IKVM. I tried to use this dll in a C# project which uses .Net Framework 2.0 but failed since the converted dlls framework obviously is higher. I looked through the arguments of the IKVM compiler but didn't find anything regarding the framework.

My question now is:

Am I able to specify the framework version of the compiled DLL/EXE with IKVM? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clear things up a bit - IKVM doesn't produce C# dlls - it produces .NET assemblies written in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of IKVM 7.1 is build with the framework 2.0. If you create a dll with IKVMC then it use by default the framework 2.0. Another thing is if you build IKVM self.

If you want compile a dll for a higher framework as 2.0 then you need to use the command line parameter:

```
-nostdlib
```

And you need to set the all needed references (like mscorlib.dll) to the target framework with the command line parameter:

```
-r:<file name>
```

Comment: I am using the current version of IKVM (I did not build it myself). However, the Framework version the Dll is using by default seems to be 3.5, that's why I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Even the 7.2 beta references 2.0. Can you show why you think yours is targeting 3.4?

Comment: I am not able to use the generated dll using targeted framework 2.0. 

Warning: The primary reference "IKVM.OpenJDK.Core" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "IKVM.OpenJDK.Core" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to my search through all the IKVM versions the IKVM 0.38.0.2 version and later all contain IKVM binaries built with framework 3.5.

0.36.0.11 was the last version depending on 2.0. That version only supports Java 6 and is way too old anyway.